# Does the phrase "Bake the cake, bigot!" have a specific origin?

Tags: united-states, discrimination, same-sex-marriage

I sometimes see the phrase "Bake the cake, bigot!" on the internet, predominantly from American conservatives mocking American liberals.

While I'm aware of more than one lawsuit involving anti-gay-marriage bakers refusing to do gay wedding cakes, I haven't been able to find a specific origin of the phrase, such as a particular lawsuit, protest, or "The Simpsons" or "South Park" episode. Is there a specific origin and context for the phrase?

Comment: I don't think etymology of memes is on topic.

Comment: What does it mean, could be on topic.  But I am agreeing that the version asking for the origin of the Meme is off topic here.

Answer (score 5):

This refers principally to baker Jack Phillips' decision to turn away David Mullins and Charlie Craig in 2012, which the Colorado state court decided was unlawful discrimination, a decision that was overturned on 4th June 2018 by the Supreme court, which ruled 7-2 that the State court had not correctly balanced Mr Phillips rights to freedom of religion.

Source [BBC - US Supreme Court backs Colorado baker's gay wedding cake snub](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-us-canada-44361162)

There [is a similar case pending in Northern Ireland](https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-northern-ireland-43976101), but it is the US case which is being referred to here.